# "[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: ..." Error, when using vuetify UI components with the vue-cli-plugin-vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

My project setup is using vue-cli with vue-cli-plugin-vuetify. 
When i want to use any of the [List Components](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists#lists), the browser console throws errors on most of the vuetify elements, like:

`[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-list-item-content> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

My guess is that i need to do some extra configuration on the file `/plugins/vuetify.js` to make the lists work but i don't know how.

My file `vuetify.js` looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'md',
})
```

`main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Questions: How can i make all components from vuetify work??

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

Basically, what i did was creating a new project with `vue create projectX` and then added vuetify with `vue add vuetify`. And now i want to be able to use the examples from the [vuetify documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists#lists). But copy&pasting the examples results in the described error...

Comment: Can you show your `main.js`?

Comment: sure, i updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating vuetify with: `npm install -S vuetify@2.0.1`

Answer (score 4):

Try `import Vuetify from 'vuetify'` instead of `import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'`

It'll import all vuetify components and you will be able to use them without any declarations.

Or if you want to stay with A-La-Carte mode, try this one:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify, {
  VCard,
  VRating,
  VToolbar,
} from 'vuetify/lib'
import { Ripple } from 'vuetify/lib/directives'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  components: {
    VCard,
    VRating,
    VToolbar,
  },
```

where VCard, VRating, etc are just example.

Comment: When i use `import Vuetify from 'vuetify'` instead of `import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'` i get the following compiling error:
`"export 'default' (imported as 'vuetify') was not found in './plugins/vuetify'`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Vuetify 2.x, you need to export Vuetify object from `vuetify.js`

**vuetify.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    dark: false // From 2.0 You have to select the theme dark or light here
  },
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi', // default - only for display purposes
  }
})
```

then import it and use in main.js

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app'
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately when i use this code the app is not rendering in the browser and the browser console throws this error: `TypeError: vuetify_lib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default is not a constructor`. Am i missing something? I am using vue version 3.8.2

Answer (score 0):

This solved this issue for me.
Docs at https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/unit-testing/#testing-efficiency suggest to create an instance pass it to mount.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  vuetify = new Vuetify()
})

const wrapper = mount(CustomCard, {
  localVue,
  vuetify
})
```